# Cannot install Ros Jade on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: robotic-arm, raspberrypi, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install the ROS Jade on my Raspberry Pi 2, which is with Ubuntu Mate 15.04 Vivid. I am getting the error  :

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-jade-desktop-full
```

Here is all my steps:

```
rafael@rafael-desktop:~$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid

rafael@rafael-desktop:~$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'

rafael@rafael-desktop:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key 0xB01FA116

Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.KUSPjeCJ2O --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/fo0bar_ubuntu_rpi2.gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key 0xB01FA116
gpg: requesting key B01FA116 from hkp server pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: key B01FA116: public key "ROS Builder <rosbuild@ros.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1

rafael@rafael-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get update

Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid InRelease                        
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid InRelease                         
Get:1 http://packages.ros.org vivid InRelease [4,015 B]
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates InRelease                            
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security InRelease
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-backports InRelease
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid Release.gpg [316 B]
Get:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid Release.gpg [933 B]
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid Release [15.1 kB]                     
Get:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates Release.gpg [933 B]                
Get:6 http://packages.ros.org vivid/main armhf Packages [4,842 B]              
Get:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security Release.gpg [933 B]
Get:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-backports Release.gpg [933 B]              
Get:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid Release [217 kB]
Get:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main armhf Packages [9,787 B]
Get:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates Release [63.5 kB]                 
Get:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main Translation-en [3,643 B]            
Get:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security Release [63.5 kB]                
Get:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-backports Release [63.5 kB]          
Get:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid/main armhf Packages [1,327 kB]       
Ign http://packages.ros.org vivid/main Translation-en_US   
Ign http://packages.ros.org vivid/main Translation-en      
Get:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted armhf Packages [7,128 B]       
Get:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid/universe armhf Packages [6,312 kB]        
Get:18 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse armhf Packages [112 kB]        
Get:19 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid/main Translation-en [793 kB]              
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse Translation-en                    
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted Translation-en                    
Get:20 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid/universe Translation-en [4,456 kB]        
Get:21 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main armhf Packages [144 kB]      
Get:22 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted armhf Packages [28 B]  
Get:23 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe armhf Packages [81.4 kB] 
Get:24 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/multiverse armhf Packages [1,339 B]
Get:25 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main Translation-en [74.7 kB]     
Get:26 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/multiverse Translation-en [1,580 B]
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted Translation-en            
Get:27 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe Translation-en [47.9 kB] 
Get:28 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main armhf Packages [82.9 kB]    
Get:29 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted armhf Packages [28 B] 
Get:30 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe armhf Packages [42.1 kB]
Get:31 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security/multiverse armhf Packages [1,339 B]
Get:32 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main Translation-en [44.9 kB]    
Get:33 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security/multiverse Translation-en [1,580 B]
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted Translation-en           
Get:34 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe Translation-en [27.1 kB]
Get:35 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/main armhf Packages [28 B]      
Get:36 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/restricted armhf Packages [28 B]
Get:37 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/universe armhf Packages [4,016 B]
Get:38 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/multiverse armhf Packages [28 B]
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/main Translation-en                
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/multiverse Translation-en          
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/restricted Translation-en          
Get:39 http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/universe Translation-en [3,760 B]
Fetched 14.0 MB in 2min 5s (112 kB/s)                                          
Reading package lists... Done

rafael@rafael-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-jade-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-jade-desktop-full
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214604/cannot-install-ros-jade-on-ubuntu-15.04/) by [rafaelsoares](https://answers.ros.org/users/23103/rafaelsoares/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-07-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-07-27**:
Many people is getting this error with Jade.

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-03-23**:
Have you thought about trying ubuntu snappy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As noted on the [ARM Install Page](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/UbuntuARM), the builds of ROS Jade for ARM only support Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben12345](https://answers.ros.org/users/21811/ben12345/) on 2015-08-12**:
Any idea when support for 15.04 will be available?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to get ROS up and running on Ubuntu / Linaro 14.04, and get stable wifi.
http://linuxcake.com/rpi2-ubuntu/
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=98997

This was helpful for the wifi - https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#Wicd
^ tried the same procedure to get wifi with Ubuntu trusty 14.04 and it still doesn't work... no idea why.

Ran into some problems with memory when i plugged a Hokuyo LiDAR in to the pi running Ubuntu Linaro though, it completely crashed. Was able to temporarily fix it by  changing the memory limit with "sudo ulimit -a" etc etc, but this is temporary and only for that terminal instance. You can change the config files to make it permanent but i can't get it to work.

If you can get snappy core 14 point whatever that might work? not looked into it massively but the wifi set up process is a bit different and might actually work. (I'm assuming that like me you tried Ubuntu Mate because the Wifi actually without you having a PhD in networking with linux?)

Hope this is of some use to someone, i think i'm going to give up and wait until some progress is made with trusty 14.04 or someone rolls out a better one. I have some single board X64 computers that'l run full desktop ubuntu so it's not a massive drama for me. I just wanted ROS running on the Pi so i had an excuse to play with the kernel and get a Pi TFT running on a robot of some nature.

Good luck guys!

---

Originally posted by [Ben12345](https://answers.ros.org/users/21811/ben12345/) with karma: 98 on 2015-08-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1